# How to set-up HOSTAPD?

Tags: wifi

I have Edimax EW-7811UN wifi dongle I'd like to create an AP with my Pi.
I've done these steps:

1. `apt-get install hostapd`
2. `iface wlan0 inet static
   address 10.0.0.1
   netmask 255.255.255.0`
   in /etc/network/interfaces
3. `DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"` 
   in /etc/default/hostapd
4. `interface=wlan0
   driver=nl80211
   ssid=PiNet
   hw_mode=g
   channel=6
   auth_algs=1
   wmm_enabled=0`
   in /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
5. `sudo service hostapd start`

If I understand it rigth, the network should be now visible and prepeared for DNS configuration.
Since none of these steps as well as others on the Internet works for me I wonder if the installed hostapd can turn the Edimax dongle into AP mode, as I've read this's possible just since v2.4.
Or more likely is there any other problem (e.g. dongle connected to the Internet while setting-up HostAPD)?
Please, note since I'm new to Pi and Linux feel free to describe your suggestions as I would totally stupid :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am struggling with something similar.m
Are you using JESSIE, if so step 2 wont work, i have just found out that you do not edit /etc/network/interfaces on JESSIE. There is a generic post on this site which explains what to do, 
[How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip)
I have not had chance to see if it solves my problem but think it will
Steve

Comment: Thanks, I will try that as comehome. Probably after reinstall of my Raspbian for sure.